# django Facebook Registration Process

Tags: python, django, facebook

I've been searching some topics concerning facebook registration. Its just that i cant find any topics on how to save the user's facebook data to my users model.

Currently, users can Login successfully in my site.

here's my code:

base.html

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() { FB.init({ appId : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', status : true,   cookie : true, xfbml  : true }); };
(function() { var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true; e.src =   document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'; document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e); }());
</script>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream" ></fb:login-button>
```

My problem is i dont know how to get the Data from facebook and save it to may users model.

do you have any idea on how to solve this problem? your answers are highly appreciated. thank you..!

Comment: any help please.. been waiting for your answers. im stuck in this task.. please help me... thanks..

Comment: Only Patience is the way to go..

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you: [Facebook Connect: capturing user data with django-profiles and django-socialregistration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973263/facebook-connect-capturing-user-data-with-django-profiles-and-django-socialregis/3973300#3973300) or you need a more verbose answer?

EDIT:
that `facebook.GraphAPI` thing can be imported from this: https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/